# aggregation sum for separated groups using pivot?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get the aggregation amount over the past rolling 3 days for each separated group. However, I don't get what I expected. Can anyone show me how to produce the expected output, maybe using pivot?

however, my result separated the groups, giving me result when the group is red, and null if it's yellow. however, I want the result such that even though the group is yellow, the data is still not null, but just duplicate the previous number. Maybe try it with pivot?

```
select *,
case when group = 'Red' then count(NVL(amount,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT, group ORDER BY day_number range 2 PRECEDING),
case when group = 'Yellow' then count(NVL(amount,0)) OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT, group ORDER BY day_number range 2 PRECEDING)
from table
```

expected output

```
Account Group   Sum day_number  Red Yellow
abc     Red     20  1           20  0
abc     Red     30  3           50  0
abc     Yellow  40  4           50  40
def     Red     20  5           20  40
def     Yellow  50  8           0   50
def     Yellow  20  9           0   70
```

wrong output

```
Account Group   Sum day_number  Red Yellow
abc     Red     20  1           20  
abc     Red     30  3           50  
abc     Yellow  40  4               40
def     Red     20  5           20  
def     Yellow  50  8               50
def     Yellow  20  9               70
```

Comment: Please post your other code to make it a working example...

Comment: Firstly remember that you have to end your *case when* with *else/end*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make `red` and `yellow` columns independent from account and group then simply remove `partition by` part.

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8c54502fbb1c8486acb8aebd9959c080)</sup>**

```
select t.*,
       nvl(sum(case grp when 'Red'    then amount end) 
           over (order by day_number range 2 preceding), 0) red,
       nvl(sum(case grp when 'Yellow' then amount end) 
           over (order by day_number range 2 preceding), 0) yellow
  from t
```

which gives us result:

```
ACCOUNT GRP        AMOUNT DAY_NUMBER        RED     YELLOW
------- ------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
abc     Red            20          1         20          0
abc     Red            30          3         50          0
abc     Yellow         40          4         30         40
def     Red            20          5         50         40
def     Yellow         50          8          0         50
def     Yellow         20          9          0         70
```

Note that there is difference in third row in column `RED` (you typed 50, query shows 30), but for day `4` we have only one red value from two previous days, which is `30`.

If you simply need to repeat values for nulls then use `lag` instead, but this makes no sense for me.

You can do it with `pivot`, but you had to *prepare* data properly in subquery, then make pivot. In this case `case when` syntax is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mostly want `sum()` instead of `count()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when group = 'Red'
             then sum(amount) over (partition by account, group order by day_number range between 2 preceding and current row)
        end) as red,
       (case when group = 'Yellow'
             then sum(amount) over (partition by account, group order by day_number range between 2 preceding and current row)
        end) as red
from table t
```

Comment: yes, sum. Thank you! But this code will give me the wrong output I displayed above. There're some missing values when group is not red. However, I don't want missing values, if group is not red, display the number same as the previous one.

Comment: @vicky . . . That was a typo in the second condition.